# Laptop Touchpad Not Working

Tags: windows-10, laptop, drivers, touchpad

So I hope this is the right place to ask this but anyways: This was my first time purchasing a laptop since I've used pcs for my whole life... I got [this one](https://www.laptopsdirect.ie/medion-deputy-p10-core-i5-10300h-16gb-512gb-ssd-15.6-inch-geforce-gtx-1660-30029473/version.asp) which looked pretty darn nice and was a pretty good deal. Long story short, It arrived, I booted it up and when I started going through the setup, I noticed the touchpad wasn't working, I brushed it off but I tried to get it to work later that day, found out Fn + F9 enables and disables the touchpad, however it was already enabled. Furthermore, I tried updating the drivers but I never even got that fat, went into the device manager and went into Mice and Pointing devices, the only one recognized was my mouse, the touchpad wasn't even there. I actually later on found that I can find the Trackpad listed in hidden devices inside Human Interface Devices in device manager, I tried updating it but it said it had the latest driver, interestingly in properties it says the device is not connected... I don't want to return it or send it for a repair mainly because I've already tried and gave up after an hour of speaking to a Customer Support Agent, I'm sure there's some way of fixing it without doing that, but it worst comes to worst, I'll bite the bullet, any ideas?

Comment: If it doesn't work on arrival, send it back. Accept no arguments from sales reps, EU law says if you bought it online you can return it even for no reason but you don't like it  [within 14 days]. The only difference is - if you don't like it you pay postage; if it's broken they pay postage. Buy something else from somewhere else. Vote with your wallet. Don't use that company again.

Comment: I'd get it replaced too. It's new, it's supposed to be perfectly working. You've received a faulty unit that's not usable without a mouse and you don't know what surprises are waiting down the line.

Comment: @Tetsujin If two people are telling me the exact same thing, I guess I'll just do that if there's no simple fix.. Was kinda hoping this was a common issue with an easy fix but nevermind haha